# Java Swing buttongroup clear on click

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, jpanel

i have one button group with 2 radio buttons:

```
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButtonESPRINCIPAL;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButtonESSECUNDARIO;
buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
```

I know that i can clear the group by buttonGroup1.clearSelection(), but i want to do this only if i click on a clicked radio button.

I have tried

```
    private void jRadioButtonESPRINCIPALMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                     
    if (jRadioButtonESPRINCIPAL.isSelected()) {
        buttonGroup1.clearSelection();
    }
    else{
        jRadioButtonESPRINCIPAL.setSelected(true);
    }
}                                                    

private void jRadioButtonESSECUNDARIOMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                      
    if (jRadioButtonESSECUNDARIO.isSelected()) {
        buttonGroup1.clearSelection();
    }
    else{
        jRadioButtonESSECUNDARIO.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

But didnt works

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: Which part of your code calls those methods ?

Comment: I feel like using [action listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) are a better choice here.

Comment: @Berger i have 2 radio buttons wich call those methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer was wrong sorry. You have to use `ActionListeners` like this:

```
    jRadioButtonESPRINCIPAL.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //your code goes here
        }
    });
```

and then use a variable to store the last `RadioButton` that was selected. In the `ActionListener` you then have to check if the `isSelected()` equals the last selection. If yes, then use `buttonGroup1.clearSelection();`.

So the final code should look like this:

```
    jRadioButtonESPRINCIPAL.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (jRadioButtonESPRINCIPAL.equals(lastSelectedRadioButton)) {
                buttonGroup1.clearSelection();
                lastSelectedRadioButton = null;
            }
            else {
                lastSelectedRadioButton = jRadioButtonESPRINCIPAL;
            }
        }
    });

    jRadioButtonESSECUNDARIO.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (jRadioButtonESSECUNDARIO.equals(lastSelectedRadioButton)) {
                buttonGroup1.clearSelection();
                lastSelectedRadioButton = null;
            }
            else {
                lastSelectedRadioButton = jRadioButtonESSECUNDARIO;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It doesnt works for me :( , i want to clear the group when you click a button wich was already clicked

Comment: I updated my answer, please try it again with the new code